# Graphing the difference of two handle-functions in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, function-handle

I have two `handle-functions`, their graphs are very close to each other, I can see this by plotting both functions.

```
f = @(x1);
ff = @(x2);
fplot(f, [0 1],'r')
hold on
fplot(ff, [0 1],'b')
hold on
```

I would like to have another graph where I take the difference between `f-ff`

```
fplot((f-ff), [0 1])
```

how can I do this in matlab? And how can I find the:

```
max(abs(f-ff))
```

when both are handle-functions?
Thanks in advance!

PS. Just let me know if I should add more info about `f` and `ff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
fplot(@(x) f(x) - ff(x), [0 1])
```

Comment: Hi @LuisMendo, thanks for your answer, I was wondering if you have a suggestion to how can I find `max(abs(f-ff))`?

Comment: You could do it numerically: define your `x` values: `x=linspace(0,1,1e5);` and then compute `max(abs(f(x)-ff(x)))`. Or you could use `fplot(@(x) abs(f(x)-ff(x)), [0 1])` and see the result graphically